# http headers with the help of javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to send http headers with the help of javascript?

Comment: Send them from what to where? Trying to achieve what?

Comment: Ha, ha, Jonathan, just remove the *"heya gangsta!"* :P

Answer (score 2):

Sure.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "/path/to/script", false);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
xhr.send(strUrlEncodedPostVariables);
```

Be careful though. IE 5, 5.5 and 6 didn't support the XMLHttpRequest object, so you had to use `new ActiveXObject()` and the implementation was wonky (but worked). I don't recall how you set headers in the ActiveXObject implementation (I think it was the same), but I remember it did allow it. Strangely, the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) on XHR is the easiest place to read up on this.